# How to redirect to log in page after click logout button on navbar header in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm new to React.  I have react router config in App.js like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/management" component={Management}>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/sign-up" component={SignUpForm}>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/sign-in" component={SignInForm}>
        </Route>
        <Route component={Error}>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter >
```

I want header to show in every page, there's a button of logout at header, I want to redirect to /sign-in page after I click it. In my header component it's like this:

```
class Header extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        redirect: false
    }

}
logout = () => {
    sessionStorage.setItem("userToken", '');
    sessionStorage.clear();
    this.setState({ redirect: true });


}
render() {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
        return (
            <Redirect to={'/sign-in'} />
        )
    }


    return (
        <div>

            <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="md" bg="dark" variant="dark" fixed="top" >
               ......
                        <NavLink to="/management" className="header-link"><FontAwesomeIcon icon="cog" size="lg" /></NavLink>
                        <button type='button' onClick={this.logout}>Log Out</button>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        </div>
    );
}
}
export default Header;
```

There will be errors "Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/sign-in", and the nav bar will disappear only the body of sign-in shows. May I know what is the correct way to do this? I also tried this.props.history.push('/sign-in') but there's no props.history, probably because header is not in route? Should i use with Router? Or should I actually just make every page import header instead put it in app.js? or what is actually the right way to do this? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement login/logout with route using HOC that checks the session item with every route change. If the session has `userToken` then it will redirect to given component otherwise will redirect to login component.

```
import React from "react"
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom"

export const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        sessionStorage.getItem('userToken') ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/sign-in"/>
    )} />
)
```

import `<PrivateRoute>` and use it as the authorized path. And keep all the other path as normal routes in which you don't want authorization.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Home} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/management" component={Management} />
            <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUpForm} />
            <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignInForm} />
            <Route component={Error} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter >
```

So while you do log out, the session item will be removed and automatically redirect to sign-in page.

```
class Header extends Component {

....

logout = () => {
    sessionStorage.removeItem("userToken");
    sessionStorage.clear(); 
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
          ...
          <button type='button' onClick={this.logout}>Log Out</button>
        </div>
    )
}
}
export default Header;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! :D So this PrivateRoute will redirect the whole page to sign in as long as the user token is removed from the session even  the header is not wrapped in <PrivateRoute> right? May I know why we write {component:Component} like this? Are "...rest" like path="/sign-up" ? And what are the props ? Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh I just tried and this method is so good! Then just add a <NavLink to="/sign-in" onClick={this.logout} className="header-link">Log Out</NavLink> !

Comment: I am glad that this solution works for you. Happy to help you. And appreciate your acknowledgement too.

Comment: Thank you so much! Oh and may I know what would be a good way to hide <Header /> when user is in sign in page and sign up page with this structure? Thank you so much!

Comment: Just put '<Header>' component in '<PrivateRoute>'  component along with mentioned component, so it will be hidden in signin/signup page and will seen in authorized routes. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55175724/proper-way-of-handling-conditional-component-render-depending-on-route/55268623#55268623

Comment: Wow thank you so much! Just put it in: export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        sessionStorage.getItem('userToken') ? <Header /> <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/sign-in" />
    )} />
) .         This method is really really great!!! Learned a lot! Thank you so much !!! Really appreciate it! :D

Answer (score 2):

Components tied up to Routes gets access to history object as prop so you can mutate it as you need, such as logging out. Since your Header component doesn't  have access to the history object, you will have to use a lower level router to give it access to the history object:

```
import { Router } from "react-router"
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history"

const history = createBrowserHistory()

<Router history={history}>
  <div className="App">
      <Header history={history} />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/management" component={Management}>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/sign-up" component={SignUpForm}>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/sign-in" component={SignInForm}>
        </Route>
        <Route component={Error}>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
</Router>
```

now inside you Header component you can call `history.push('/login')`

see reference: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router/history-object

Comment: Thank you so much! Just tried this and it worked. May I know what's the difference between react-router and react-router-dom? Since it does not allow me to import BrowserRouter. And I just realize that I can also use NavLink to="/sign-in" for the sign out button, May I know what's the difference between using NavLink to or Redirect to? Thank you so much!

Comment: react-router contains the lower level components, react-router-dom contains contains browser specific components. Just remember that it is important that any component you have is pointing to the same history object so your history is from a single source because otherwise you will get bugs with your history not synchronizing with browser. Can i have my answer accepted? You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches you're mentioning here. You can use the higher order component ['withRouter'](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) that gives components access to the history object. By using the [history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/history) object that would get passed to your component as a prop, you can push to the route you want.

Personally, I like setting up my signout links to render a component that houses the log-out logic and renders a redirect to log-in once it's complete. That way users can go directly to the sign-out link if they want, and you can link to it from anywhere in your app as needed, without having to duplicate the logic.

In your browser router, you can add a path for "/logout" that renders a component like this (based on your logic):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

export default class LogOut extends Component {
    state = {
        redirect: false,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        sessionStorage.setItem("userToken", '');
        sessionStorage.clear();
        this.setState({ redirect: true });
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.redirect ?
            <Redirect to={'/sign-in'} /> :
            null;
    }
}
```

Normally I would make an ajax request to clear a session and then setState once that's complete, but yours is all server-side.

Comment: Thank you so much! I currently feel very confused that my logout button is in my header and this button will do the logout function, but I don't know how to structure the header or the route. The header shows in every page so it seems I should not use redirect in header's render return,  or I shouldn't put <header /> above the routes in app.js? May I know how would you structure the logic? Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you soooo much for your help! I'm super confused with the route and authentication thing together~

Comment: Updated @Ying. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! Then I just import the logout button to my header right? Oh and after I click the sign out button, may I know how to re render the page body? Like I'm in the management page with some user info, then I click the sign out button on the header, how can I make the body of management page to sign in page?

Comment: @Ying You would be able to render it like you are the NavLink for /management, or any Link except to /logout. Your route would handle rendering the component, ex: <Route path="/logout" component={LogOut}>

Comment: Ah Thank you so much!!! That's really really helpful! :D Ah last question, may I know how to hide NavLink for /management  or the whole header bar if I'm in sign-in page?

Comment: @Ying Since you're handling session by a cookie set in the browser, you can check if that's set, and then only render the link if it's set: {isLoggedIn &&<NavLink to="/management" />}. Ideally, you'd also block the user from being able to navigate to the management URL as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! :D Learned a lot!

Comment: @dhara-charola's answer has great stuff about how to protect your routes and handle the state!!

Comment: I need an example of how to set the layout structure to when not authenticated show only login page and when logged in show the whole page with sidebar menus, can you point me an example or tutorial showing that?

Comment: To solve the error "export 'Redirect' (imported as 'Redirect') was not found in 'react-router-dom'", use the Navigate component instead of Redirect, e.g. <Navigate to="/dashboard" replace={true} />.

The Navigate component changes the current location when it's rendered.

Answer (score 0):

After Logout redirecting to pages on display with Direct URL , on Logout clear the localStorage and check for username, If its null redirection will be done to login page.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class AnyPage extends Component {
    state = {
        redirect: true,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("username") === null){
      this.setState({ redirect: true });
    }else{
      this.setState({ redirect: false });
    }
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.redirect ?
            <Navigate to={'/login'} /> :(<>Page Details</>);
    }
}
```