# How to navigate on a page without reloading the page

Tags: reactjs

I have navigation in react and want to redirect to the listing page on click.using this right now which is loading the page

This is my Header.js file

```
return (
<Link to="/allusers">All Users</Link>
);
```

This is my App.js file
I imported this

```
import UsersList from './user/UsersList'; //then i defined 
class App extends Component {
render () {
return (
<BrowserRouter>
<div>
<Header />
 <Switch>
<Route exact path='/userlist' component={UsersList} />
 </Switch>
</div>
</BrowserRouter>
)
}
}
```

Comment: I think you need you checkout `react-router` https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: I don't see the import of 'react-router-dom' in your App.js component, do you have imported it? also in your code change goToUserList function to  gotToUserList = () => {}.

Comment: Use `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter` in `react-router`

Answer (score 0):

You can check `react-router` or `@reach/router`

For example, in @reach/router, you can use the provided `Link` component to create the same anchor as in your example:

`<Link to="/userlist">All Users</Link>`

And create a router with all your routes:

```
<Router primary={false}>
    <Home path="/" />
    <AllUsers path="/allusers" />
    <NotFound default />
</Router>
```

https://github.com/reach/router

You can play around with this example: https://reach.tech/router/tutorial/04-router

Same thing can be done with react-router.

Answer (score 0):

This achieved through a client side routing: manipulation of the history object of the browser through client side

This is an example rendering a specific component for specific route

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom"

<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
    <Route exact path="/allusers" component={AllUsers} />
    <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>

// then just pair it up with a navigation bar

<Link to="/">All Users</Link>
<Link to="/allusers">All Users</Link>
```

These components tied up to a route has access to history object as prop where you can call `history.push('/allusers')` for other use cases

reference:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: When i am using link its reloading the page

Comment: are you sure it's reloading? check your debugger

Comment: Yes its reloading the page.. When i use button onClick event its not even triggered.

Comment: can you show me your codes? per file show them. the one on your question is cluttered

Comment: @shikha check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520500/how-to-redirect-to-log-in-page-after-click-logout-button-on-navbar-header-in-rea/55521261#55521261

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as follows:

```
goToUserList = () => {
    this.props.history.push('/userlist')
}

...
return(
    <button onClick={this.goToUserList}>Go User List</button>
)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Button is not working on click event is not triggered in my case.

Comment: Can you add some relevant code, so that we could check what might be happening? Thanks